# Is it possible to go straight to the print process with JavaScript without loading an html page?

Tags: javascript, ajax, printing

I mean: user click some "print" button and printer start printing. Is it that possible?

Please take in account that already exist a server process behind (via AJAX) that can return success to print (or html to show, whatever) or error to show an alert. That is not the problem.

EDIT:

After some quick comments (thanks!) **I meant "open print dialog" not "start printing"**.

Comment: I think that's not possible as it would break the sandboxing the browser provides around the javascript code: being able to print a document without the user's consent would give way to many inappropriate uses of said function, and also override default system behaviors.

Comment: Hopefully not. That would mean visiting a website has the freedom to waste paper here.

Comment: Thankfully you cannot do this, no.

Comment: The javascript print function simply tells the browser to open the print dialog.

Comment: i agree, not possible, unless this is a vulnerability....

Comment: OK, thanks all. I meant "open print dialog".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have an HTML page; the one where the button is. You can have different style sheets for the page for the screen and the printer using the `media` asttribute or `@media` directive. You can have different looks and layout for when the page is printed, or you can even have a completely different set of elements.

Example:

```
#PrintContent { display: none; }

@media print {

   #RegularContent { display: none; }
   #PrintContent { display: block; }

}
```

To have the button print the page, just use the `print` method:

```
<input type="button" onclick="window.print();" value="Print me!" />
```

This will of course not just start printing, but opens the print dialog. To print something without that dialog you would need to run a component in the browser, but starting the component would require user confirmation, so you would get a dialog anyway, and a much more intimidating one.

Comment: Thanks Guffa. Yes, I did know what you say. I asked using a bad concept (due to my spanish->english buggy processor :)) I meant open immediately the "print dialog". And moreover: I don't want print the current page! is needed a server process that results in a different data returned. Thanks!

Comment: @NomikOS: You can fetch the content using AJAX and put it in a container in the page that is only visible for the print media, that way you don't have to display another page to print the content.

Comment: Thanks, So the answer to my question is that "is not possible". Yes, I'll use the code that you suggest with html returned via AJAX. Thanks again for your help... I give you a few more points to add to your amazing ranking! THX!

Answer (score 0):

I would open a new page that displays the print HTML from the server and call `window.print()` from its onload handler

Comment: I don't want open a new page for this. That is the point. But thanks Juan for your answer! :)